# Limit gives two different answers depending on approach

Tags: calculus, limits

So I have a function
$$g(t)=\frac{f'(t)\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})-0.5\cos(\frac{t-x}{2})[f(t)-f(x)]}{\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})^2}$$.

Then, I want to find
$$\lim_{t \to x}g(t) $$ assuming that $$f''(t)$$ exists.

Using L'Hopital, I get that
$$\lim_{t \to x}g(t)=f''(t)$$ which seems like the right answer based on some functions I tested. Just to give a derivation of this approach, I apply L'Hopital by noting that both the numerator and denominator approach 0, and I get after canceling some terms in the numerator
$$\lim_{t \to x}g(t)=\lim_{t \to x}\frac{f''(t)\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})+0.25\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})[f(t)-f(x)]}{\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})\cos(\frac{t-x}{2})}$$.
This then gives when canceling the $\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})$ terms
$$\lim_{t \to x}g(t)=\lim_{t \to x}\frac{f''(t)+0.25[f(t)-f(x)]}{\cos(\frac{t-x}{2})}=f''(x)$$

But, I get a different answer based on my approach below:

I first rewrite $g(t)$ as
$$g(t)=\frac{f'(t)}{\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})}-\frac{0.5\cos(\frac{t-x}{2})}{\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})}\frac{[f(t)-f(x)]}{\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})}]$$.

Now, taking the limit and applying product and sum limit rules I get

$$\lim_{t \to x}g(t)=\lim_{t \to x}[\frac{f'(t)}{\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})}]-\lim_{t \to x}[\frac{0.5\cos(\frac{t-x}{2})}{\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})}]*\lim_{t \to x}[\frac{[f(t)-f(x)]}{\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})}]$$

Then, using L'Hopital, I have that
$$\lim_{t \to x}[\frac{[f(t)-f(x)]}{\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})}=2f'(x)$$.

Plugging this into the $g(t)$ limit I get that
$$\lim_{t \to x}g(t)=\lim_{t \to x}[\frac{f'(t)}{\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})}]-\lim_{t \to x}[\frac{\cos(\frac{t-x}{2})}{\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})}]*f'(x)$$
which when taking everything under the same limit equals
$$\lim_{t \to x}g(t)=\lim_{t \to x}[\frac{f'(t)-f(x)}{\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})}]$$.
Applying L'Hopital one last time above gives

$$\lim_{t \to x}g(t)=2f''(x)$$

Why is this answer off by a factor of 2? Is there some limit rule I am violating? Sorry if there are any formatting issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated, this has been driving me s.

Comment: x needs to be a constant for l’hopitals rule to work.

Comment: It is an arbitrary constant. t is the  only variable here.

Comment: Just thought I’d let u know

Comment: For the ease of typing one can use the substitution $t=x+2h$ with $h\to 0$ and the desired limit is equal to the limit of $\frac{2f'(x+2h)\sin h-\cos h(f(x+2h)-f(x))}{2h^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second approach you are in effect applying the non-rule
$$\lim \frac{a(t) + b(t)f(t)}{c(t)}
=\lim \frac{a(t) + b(t)\lim f(t)}{c(t)},$$
i.e., you are selectively letting $t\to x$ in part of your expression, holding $t$ constant in the rest, then letting $t\to x$ in the whole expression. In general this is not legal; the fact that you're still dividing by $c(t)$ makes this operation dubious. For example, try this move on the limit
$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t-t\cos t}{t^3}.$$ If you first let $t\to0$ in $\cos t$ alone, the limit becomes $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t - t}{t^3}=-\frac16,$$ which is wrong; the correct answer is $\frac13$.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. So you cannot take the limit product rule in the case where one of the limits is indeterminate?

Comment: Right, in the limit product rule both of the limits must exist (and the result cannot be $0\cdot\infty$). Similarly you cannot apply the limit sum rule to achieve a result of $\infty - \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

In the first attempt I've made a similar mistake for the $f(t)-f(x)$ term, here is the correct way to proceed without L'Hospital

$$g(t)=\frac{f'(t)\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})-\frac12\cos(\frac{t-x}{2})[f(t)-f(x)]}{\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})^2}=$$

$$=\frac{f'(t)\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})-f'(x)\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})+f'(x)\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})-\frac12\cos(\frac{t-x}{2})[f(t)-f(x)]}{\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})^2}=$$

$$=2\frac{f'(t)-f'(x)}{t-x}\frac{\frac{t-x}{2}}{\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})}+\frac{f'(x)\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})-\frac12\cos(\frac{t-x}{2})[f(t)-f(x)]}{\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})^2} \to f''(x)$$

indeed

$$2\frac{f'(t)-f'(x)}{t-x}\frac{\frac{t-x}{2}}{\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})} \to 2f''(x)$$

and since

- $\sin(\frac{t-x}{2}) = \frac{t-x}{2}+o((t-x)^2)$
- $\cos(\frac{t-x}{2}) = 1-\frac12(\frac{t-x}{2})^2+o((t-x)^2)$
- $f(t)-f(x)=f'(x)(t-x)+\frac12f''(x)(x-t)^2+o((t-x)^2)$

we have

$$\frac{f'(x)\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})-\frac12\cos(\frac{t-x}{2})[f(t)-f(x)]}{\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})^2}=$$

$$\require{cancel}
=\frac{\cancel{f'(x)\frac{t-x}{2}}-\cancel{\frac12f'(x)(t-x)}-\frac14f''(x)(x-t)^2+o((t-x)^2)}{\left(\frac{t-x}{2}\right)^2+o((t-x)^2)}=$$

$$-\frac{f''(x)+o(1)}{1+o(1)}\to -f''(x)$$

Comment: Sorry, I can add an approach to my first L'Hopital approach. It seems like you got what I got with the second approach, but if you test this with say f(t)=t^3 and x=2, you will get from the graph that as t goes to 2, g(t) will go to 12 which is one half of what you obtained.

Comment: Also some step in your second method is not much clear to me. I will take a closer look later also to your example.

Answer (score 0):

Write $g(t)$ as
$$g(t)=\frac{\left(\frac{t-x}{2}\right)^2\cos(\frac{t-x}{2})}{\left[\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})\right]^2}\cdot\frac{f'(t)\tan(\frac{t-x}{2})-0.5[f(t)-f(x)]}{\left(\frac{t-x}{2}\right)^2}.$$
Using
$$ \tan x=x+O(x^3)$$
one has
$$g(t)=\frac{\left(\frac{t-x}{2}\right)^2\cos(\frac{t-x}{2})}{\left[\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})\right]^2}\cdot\frac{f'(t)(1+O((t-x)^3)-0.5[f(t)-f(x)]}{\left(\frac{t-x}{2}\right)^2} $$
and hence
$$\lim_{t\to x}g(t)=\lim_{t\to x}\frac{\left(\frac{t-x}{2}\right)^2\cos(\frac{t-x}{2})}{\left[\sin(\frac{t-x}{2})\right]^2}\cdot\frac{f'(t)(1+O((t-x)^3)-0.5[f(t)-f(x)]}{\left(\frac{t-x}{2}\right)^2}=\lim_{t\to x}\frac{f'(t)-0.5[f(t)-f(x)]}{\left(\frac{t-x}{2}\right)^2}=f''(x). $$